# Subscribe after collect doesn't work

Tags: java, android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm experimenting with RxJava. I need an `Observable`, which produces a `HashSet<String>`. Into `Observable` I want to be abele to put `Pair<String, Boolean>` in the way that `false` boolean value removes the `String` key from the resulting `HashSet`. Here's a code snippet of what I have:

```
private val selectionSubject = ReplaySubject.create<Pair<String, Boolean>>()
init {
    selectionSubject.onNext(Pair("dd", false))
    selectionSubject
        .collect({HashSet<String>()}, {dest, value -> collectSelection(dest, value)})
        .subscribe { t1, t2 -> Log.d(TAG, t1.toString())}
}

private fun collectSelection(dest: HashSet<String>, value: Pair<String, Boolean>): HashSet<String> {
    if (value.second) {
        dest.add(value.first)
    } else {
        dest.remove(value.first)
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "collectSelection, ${dest.toString()}")
    return dest
}
```

In the logs I can see that `collectSelection` gets called but my subscribe listener doesn't.

How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`collect` waits for `onComplete` event from the stream above before emitting a value. In your case, `ReplaySubject` never ends and thus no value is emitted.

Without knowing the context of `selectionSubject` I can't provide a solution to your problem, like, does it have to remain open? If there are limited `onNext` calls, you can use `.take(X)`. If it has to remain open, you shouldn't depend on collect but add the item inside on `HashSet` in something like `.doOnNext`

Comment: It has to remain open. I want to be able to continously put there new items and have the HashSet as result. So, whenever I add a new item the new HashSet must be produces in a reactive way.

Comment: In that case you are wasting a lot of memory and computation power recreating the set after each value. `HashSet` should be in class scope instead of function scope. Use 1 `PublishSubject` for Pair and in it's `onSubscribe.onNext` add value to `HashSet. Use another Publish/BehaviorSubject to provide the HashSet to other subscribers and send a new update every time there's a new pair in the first subject.

Comment: Yeah, storing the Set on the class level is an obvous approach. It can also be done via custom Subject I guess. But I though that there's smth built-in, which allows to achieve the same. If there won't be any better answer I'll accept yours. Thanks!